# Get external IP address of a website

Tags: c#, .net, dns, ip-address

I have seen many methods for easily retrieving the internal IP address of a machine or website. However, I can't seem to find a good way to retrieve the external IP address.

To clarify, if I provide a URL like bitbucket.org, I want to get the external IP address of bitbucket. Is there a web service out there that can easily do this?

**EDIT:** Suppose, for this case, that I am on the same network as bitbucket.org.

I am filling a database with information about all the websites our company manages. We want to keep track of the info and note periodic changes, with specific data. This program will be deployed on one of the local servers on the same network as the servers that the websites are running from. I believe the only good way of retrieving the external IP address for each site is to use an external web service.

Comment: What code have you written to do this, so far?

Comment: If you're not on bitbucket's network yourself, won't you only get the external address? What's the difference?

Comment: whatever the c# equivalent of `get_addr_by_host('bitbucket.com')` is? e.g. do a DNS lookup.

Comment: @Rup, in this case, let's suppose I am on the same network as BitBucket.

Comment: @Brian I have tried all possible suggestions that I've found on the internet, but they are just as I described in the post above.

Comment: I think this depends on how exactly is your local network configured.

Comment: @WesleyPorter - Honestly, the best solution might be for you to just roll your own web service and host it on an ASP.NET server that is on a completely external 3rd party server.

Comment: @icemanind - Perhaps... I've thought of that. I appreciate you taking time to investigate :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx) to get IP address by the host name.

Comment: Sorry, Alex, this is the same as getting the internal IP address when on the same network.

Comment: It isn't nessecarily, but if you are using an internal DNS server or if your router is doing DNS fixup it could give you the wrong IP.  What you really need is a web service that does a dns lookup on your behalf, but I'm not aware of anything that does that.

Answer (score 3):

You could query an external public DNS server, e.g. Google's one at 8.8.8.8. From the command line

```
nslookup bitbucket.org 8.8.8.8
```

or in Linux `dig bitbucket.org @8.8.8.8`. There's a few C# libraries out there that will let you query a specific DNS server e.g. [DnsNet](https://github.com/spencerhakim/DnsNet) built on top of this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23673/DNS-NET-Resolver-C) (found searching - I haven't tried it to recommend it). This does rely on Google continuing the service, though, but that seems safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ping utility.  In windows, open up a command window by hitting the windows key + r and type

```
ping bitbucket.org
```

Comment: I believe the recommended answer (using System.Dns.GetHostEntry()) boils down to the same principle, but with less steps.

Comment: Both answers are wrong and do not address the question at hand. This will only return the internal IP address when on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use [Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) to get the IP Address. From the MSDN Documentation:

> The GetHostAddresses method queries a DNS server for the IP addresses associated with a host name.

UPDATE:

If you are looking for a web service, try looking at [whoisxmpapi.com](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/). As you can see from [this sample](http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/documentation/WhoisRecord.xml), they do provide the name server IP Address in their XML output. You can then use something like [this](http://www.kloth.net/services/nslookup.php) to get the IP address directly from the name server!

Comment: This is the same as all the answers above and is incorrect while on the same network. This method can never guarantee to return the external IP address.

Comment: @WesleyPorter - You are saying that if you were on the same network as `bitbucket.org` you want to know how to get the external address of the same network you are on?

Comment: Yup! That's what my question states :-). I would then have to use some external web service or something similar.

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding like such a stickler on this... I suppose I'm just frustrated from so much searching. I am already using whoisxmlapi.com for some other data. However, they don't always provide an IP address; hence, my search had continued. I have also pulled up kloth.net, but it is not a web service that I can call within my project.

Comment: @WesleyPorter - How about [Whois-RWS](https://www.arin.net/resources/whoisrws/index.html)? I don't know if its free though, if thats a requirement.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get your "wan" ip instead of your local IP you could try something like this.
You could also add code like this inside a webservice and add it to the PC bitbucket is on (if it is really on your network and you can have access to install webservices).

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property IpAddress() As String
        Get
            If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_ipAddress) Then
                Try
                    Dim webClient As New WebClient
                    Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org")

                    Dim fields = result.Split(" ")
                    _ipAddress = fields.Last
                    _ipAddress = _ipAddress.Replace("</body></html>", "")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    _ipAddress = "errorFindingIp"
                End Try
            End If
            Return _ipAddress
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I've tried that approach. You can only get the IP address of the machine you are working from, but the website can reside on a different server within the same network. This solution is also void :-(.

Comment: I'd recommend you add a webservice to the machine with a method called get public IP address or something, then add the code I've shown into the webservice.  Then calling this will get you the public IP whether you are on same network or not.

Comment: A local web service would have the same issues.

Comment: The code is going to an external client: Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://checkip.dyndns.org") If you know you are on same network this code will work. As the wan IP of the server will be the same as the WAN Ip of machines accessing the internet on same network.  And if this was installed on the server machine even better.

Comment: Yes, but this program isn't being run from each site individually. It's being run from one single location. There are multiple servers where the websites reside, so this cannot work.

Comment: Surely these servers will all have the same WAN Ip address and a different local IP address if they are all on the same network as your question suggests.